# Cannot debug or run file in VS Code 2015

Tags: c++, c, json, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the latest Visual Studio code (Version 1.2.1). The biggest problem is that I can't debug or run my file.

When I press **F5** to run, it asks me to *open folder*.

When I open the folder from *file*, it creates a **launch.json** file and still shows this error after pressing **F5**

`Cannot launch program 'c:\Users\user_name\Desktop\C\file.cpp'; configuring source maps might help.`

Now I enabled `source maps` by putting the value `true` in **launch.json**.

But now its showing new error

`Cannot launch program 'c:\Users\user_name\Desktop\C\file.cpp'; setting the 'outDir' attribute might help.`

Now I don't know what is this `outDir` and what link should I put in front of it. I have tried to put the link of my file.ccp's location but still the error is same. I have also tried to put the link of folder named **out** where my VS code is installed. Also there is no **app.js** file in this version of VS Code.

Here is my actual **launch.json** which is made by default.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.cpp",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Things I have already installed on my PC are

**Git (version 2.9.0),

Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable(x86) 2015,

Microsoft Visual Studio Code,

Node.js**.

My *file.cpp* is a simple `hello world` program written in C++.

Comment: i do not know a way to debug with VSCode - it's a code editor? But you can use completion and check tools like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mitaki28.vscode-clang) and for debugging i would use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Otherwise if you are on Windows you could simply use Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 which also ships with compiler + debugger (Visual C++ Compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but isn't Microsoft Visual Studio Code just a code **editor**?

You need a **compiler** also.

Comment: then why there is option for debug? I am completely confused :( and its even not debugging

Comment: My guess is that the debug option will try to start up the debugger for the language in question, but you have neither debugger nor compiler installed.

Comment: you were right bro. Thanks for kind information. Actually i am new here and don't know much about these stuffs. Now I am downloading Visual Studio. My teacher recommended me for turboC++ but that was too old, so i installed eclipse but that was also not working properly. If you can recommend any good compiler other than TurboC++, Eclipse, and VS then that would be great help for me. Again thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new solution. Then add one or more projects that will then contain your files. You will then be able to run